# Is it possible to remove specific quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to do a replay of Skyrim, but I don't want to play the same quests again, as I'm tired of them. Is there a way to remove the quests I don't want to play? I'd probably supplement the game with community-created quests.

Comment: I've reworded the question to not ask specifically for a mod recommendation, and to ask for any solution instead. Voting to reopen as per the meta posts: […looking for mods for specific purposes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11578/4797) "*Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves a mod, so be it*", and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797) "*This is not a shopping recommendation (a request for subjective… advice). The problem can be clearly stated and objectively evaluated in most cases.*"

Answer (score 3):

You could install [The Choice Is Yours](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26359/) also [The Choice Is Yours for SSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/3850/?) - this doesn't "remove" quests, but what it does do is stop them from automatically being added to your journal - if you want to undertake a quest you will have to agree to undertake it rather than it being forced upon you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use console commands to complete this quests. Full list of commands you can find [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29), but you'll need this two: CompleteQuest  to finish quest and showquesttargets to get IDs of all quests in your journal.

Comment: This should also let me perform quests in certain quest lines I may not have finished, right? That might be best, since I've started many quest lines I have never finished.

Comment: Just save and try to use fiven quest console commands. I think you should use SetStage command to go throught partical quests, but always save before next step, because sometimes such rude switching may cause errors in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mod to do the exact thing, it called [Skyrim Quest Deleter](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/28668/)

Comment: Quest Deleter is very unstable, at least with Special Edition.  It crashes in between operations, and is not able to find quest or item IDs properly.  Not recommended.